# How can I get date, time and day from open weather API in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a date, time and day from [`open weather`](https://openweathermap.org) API of a specific location and specific day using latitude and longitude. But it gives me a long integer something like this `1525974999`. How can I retrieve date time and day from this?

Comment: Show us the code you are using. See [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Time API:

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond(1525974999) // returns: 2018-05-10T17:56:39Z
```

Using old Java `Date`:

```
new Date(1525974999 * 1000L) // returns: Thu May 10 13:56:39 EDT 2018
```

<sup>*I'm in Eastern US time zone*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's probably in seconds.  Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeReturnedByAPI * 1000);

int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Here is the Calendar API: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar

Edit: You may want to use the version of getInstance that takes a time zone to get the local time.

Edit 2: Updated in response to comments.

Comment: It's in seconds

Comment: But how can I get a date, time and day from here?

Answer (score 0):

The integer represents the amount of time it has been passed since January, 1, 1970. (Unix Time Stamp)

You can use a converter from unix time stamp or just do the math programmatically.